# Ionic Framework hide tabs on specific page

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using ionic framework and I've created a new tab application.

What I need to do is to have a page as default or home page that doesn't have the tabs and then all the rest to have the tabs as normal.

Like a landing page.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In recent ionic versions, this is easily achieved by setting

```
$ionicTabsDelegate.showBar(false);
```

Sample Code:

```
.directive('hideTabs', function($rootScope, $ionicTabsDelegate) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $el) {
      $scope.$on("$ionicView.beforeEnter", function () {
        $ionicTabsDelegate.showBar(false);
      });
      $scope.$on("$ionicView.beforeLeave", function () {
        $ionicTabsDelegate.showBar(true);
      });
    }
  };
})
```

[**SOURCE**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicTabsDelegate/)

Comment: Where to add this directive? in tabs.ts?

Answer (score 8):

**[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/sO8aUa?p=info)**

First define a separate `$stateProvider` for landing or default page [I think you already defined a `$stateProvider` for other pages] in **`app.js`**.The **`app.js`** file should be like this,

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('tabs', {
      url: '/tab',
      controller: 'TabsCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
    })
    .state('tabs.home', {
      url: '/home',
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
           controller: 'homeCtrl',
          templateUrl: 'home.html'
        }
      }
    })  
    .state('tabs.settings', {
      url: '/settings',
      views: {
        'settings-tab': {
           controller: ' signOutCtrl',
          templateUrl: 'settings.html'
        }
      }
    });
     $stateProvider
        .state('landing', {
            url: '/landing',
            controller: 'landingCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'landing.html'
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/landing');
});
```

Also create a html page for tabs.

**tabs.html**

```
<ion-view title="Home">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" ng-click="openMenu()"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-positive">
        <ion-tab title="{{tab1Title}}" icon="ion-home" href="#/tab/home">
            <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>
        <ion-tab title="{{tab2Title}}" icon="ion-gear-a" href="#/tab/settings">
            <ion-nav-view name="settings-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>
        <ion-tab title="{{tab3Title}}" href="#/landing" icon="ion-log-out">
        </ion-tab>
    </ion-tabs>
</ion-view>
```

Also you need to hide  `<ion-nav-bar>` in your **`landing`** page by using `hide-nav-bar="true "`.

**landing.html**

```
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true ">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" ng-click="openMenu()"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-content padding="true">
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">Welcome To Landing Page</h1>
        <a class="button icon-right ion-chevron-right button-calm" ng-click="open()">Lets Go</a>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 7):

It is so simple to try this

```
<!-- in your tabs.html add this ng-class -->
    <ion-tabs ng-class="{'tabs-item-hide': hideTabs}">

    </ion-tabs>

    <!-- add 'hide-tabs'in your view where you want to hide the tabs -->
    <ion-view hide-tabs> 

    </ion-view>

    // in your app.js add a directive
    .directive('hideTabs', function($rootScope) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function($scope, $el) {
                $rootScope.hideTabs = true;
                $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                    $rootScope.hideTabs = false;
                });
            }
        };
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this is a simple example …**

**Step 1)**
The default app has three tabs in the tab bar by default, namely **home**, **about** and **contact**. Let’s say that we want to hide the tab bar when the user navigates to the about tab. For that, we will need to make changes to the about.ts file which you can find at

**about.ts**

```
export class AboutPage {
  tabBarElement: any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.tabBarElement = document.querySelector('.tabbar.show-tabbar');
  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.tabBarElement.style.display = 'none';
  }

  ionViewWillLeave() {
    this.tabBarElement.style.display = 'flex';
  }
```

**Step 2)**
**about.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
       <ion-buttons left>
        <button ion-button icon-only (click)="takeMeBack()">
           <ion-icon name="arrow-back"></ion-icon>
       </button>
     </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>
      About
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  This is About Page Tab bar is Hidden.
</ion-content>
Step 3)
```

**about.ts**

```
 takeMeBack() {
    this.navCtrl.parent.select(0);
  }
```

Comment: How to do it in React?